# The CSS on the reason for edit field is broken when reviewing edits

Tags: bug, design

I saw this when I reviewed an edit.

[image: Crunched up text]

I think the CSS is messed up. But on [looking back on it](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/16053/revisions), everything looks ok.

Is this a known issue?

Comment: there's a number of issues like this with the new CSS; a refresh of the page tends to fix it. I'd report it up to meta.se

Comment: This seems to be the [same issue](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6823/unusual-character-placement-on-answer-screens)